# Differnce between $scope.Variable and $scope.Function in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-digest

```
$scope.some_random_variable = "random_value";
$scope.some_random_function = function(random_param){
    console.log("randomness");
}
```

I want to know the difference in the context of digest cycle. 
As far as I can understand scope_function changes the visibility of Angular Function.

Comment: Please tell me if I am not clear?

Comment: "As far as I can understand scope_function changes the visibility of Angular Function." what do you mean by that?  btw there is no `scope_function` here

Answer (score 0):

basically, in your html, or whatever that interacts with your `$scope`, a `$scope.something` that is declared as a function will be launched when it is called, just like how a javascript function works, same as a variable, only difference between a `$scope` and a var would be that `$scope` is a global call.